# json.stringify return value

Tags: json, return-value, stringify

I'm trying to get datatypes of a JSON.stringify to compare them.

I had used:

```
var id = d.patogeno;
alert(id);
```

But it tell the alert that is not defined.

I got this database:

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([ 
 ["node/9837102", "node/26794", "Customer", "patongenoA", "1412451.0", 3, 520, "1412381"],
  ["node/9837102", "node/44210", "Customer", "patongenoB", "1436765.0", 2, 384, "1436693"],

]);


and the following function:

function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime) {

 var node_set = new Set();
  var links = [];
  var nodetype = d3.set();
  startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt = endnodes[i];
    node_set.add({
      id: src,
      type: startnodetype[i]
    });
    node_set.add({
      id: tgt,
      type: endnodetype[i]
    });
    links.push({
      source: src,
      target: tgt,
      paytime: PayTime[i],
      patogeno: TXN_COUNT[i], // cambio ---- variable con cual trabajar
      total_amt: Total_Amt[i],
      SendTime: SendTime[i],
      value: 1
    });
  });
```

I need to know the value **of every patogeno and return it to compare it**. Is there a way to do it?, or How to return a specific value, for example: **"patogenoB" from IDData**?

Answer (score 0):

First, `JSON.stringify` produces a `string`.

```
const obj = {example: 5}
const str = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(typeof str) // 'string'
```

If you want an addressable object, you would do the reverse to a `string`:

```
const str = '{"example": 5}'
const obj = JSON.parse(str)
console.log(obj.example) // 5
```

I do not know how to answer your question with respect to `JSON.stringify`, nor do I understand why you would be turning an array of arrays into a string instead of converting them into addressable objects, but at the very end of `createNodes`, you would be able to do this:

```
links.forEach((d) => console.log(d.patogeno))
```

Comment: thanks I used your recommendation at the end and it works! It creates me a list 3, 2.  The question is how to compare those numbers with an if statement. `links.forEach((d) => console.log( if (d.patogeno == 3 ) {alert("yes"); })?`  I want to compare the information to change the color of the nodes. Is there other simple way to do it?

Comment: You haven't included nearly enough of your source for me to guess where "color" is set or what a "node" is, let alone understand how and where you're using this function or what you're doing with the result (which appears to be `void`).

Comment: Dear @Ian MacDonald its a long code, I had uploaded here: (http://www.lab-adyc.cl/test/p6.html) The idea is to choose one datatype of every array of nodes and if it is 2 of `d.patogeno` or d.`TXN_COUNT` node blue for example. I had make some marks on the code.